# Problem w/ Icons and Folders on Desktop after Update

Tags: nautilus, desktop-icons

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, and after an update tonight, there are duplicate files on my desktop. I use Nautilus for my desktop. The files are the same, one is larger, one is smaller. I have spent over an hour trying to remedy this, including un-installing and re-installing files. It is very annoying as I like using my desktop. Thank you for your help.